# Invert number and symbol in keypad

Tags: mac, keyboard

In french keyboard the number is accessible with shift key. I use British keyboard because I found that's more practical to have access on symbols.

But I like the idea of having access to the number with the shift key.

It's possible to invert the comportment in UK layout ?

Answer (score 1):

You could easily make a custom layout that does what you want with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele). [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/knrjwiot5srttpc/British%20NumShift.keylayout.zip?dl=0) is one you can try.

Comment: Thx for you answer, I help me to found [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html) and [shortcat](https://shortcatapp.com/)